# Prove that there are intersecting permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Two permutations $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{2010}$ and
>   $b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_{2010}$ of the numbers $1,2,\cdots,2010$ are said to intersect if $a_k=b_k$ for some value $k$ in the range $1\le k \le
> 2010$. Show that there exist $1006$ permutations of the numbers $1,2,\cdots,2010$ such that any other such permutation is guaranteed
>   to intersect at least one of these $1006$ permutations.

Well, I have the feeling that I should approach this using the Pigeonhole Principle, but I don't have any idea how to start.

Any help would surely be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might get more intuition for the problem by trying with smaller numbers like 3 or 4 instead of 2010.

Comment: Further hint: There exist $3$ permutations of the numbers $1,2,3,4$ s.t. any other permutation intersects at least one of these $3$ permutations.  Can you construct such $3$ permutations?

Comment: Till now I could only get at least $4$ permutations s.t. any other permutations intersect at least one of them, but not $3$...

Answer (score 1):

HINT

There exist $3$ permutations, call them $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3$, of the numbers $\{1,2,3,4\}$ s.t. any other permutation $\pi$ intersects at least one of these 3 $\sigma_i$ permutations. Can you construct such 3 permutations?

Further hint: Consider the value $1$.  It has to be in some position in $\sigma_1$, and whatever position it's in, that would prevent $\pi$ from having $1$ in the same position (or else they would intersect).  Now you have $3$ different $\sigma$'s and therefore can "block out" up to $3$ different positions for the value $1$, so $\pi$ must have the value $1$ in the remaining position.  But you haven't used value $2$ for blocking...

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Hmm...I have got the $3$ permutations, but I am not sure I can extend this up to $2010$ numbers since I did a bit "bash" to find these $3$ permutations by considering each position of the numbers...

Comment: What are your 3 permutations?  Show them to me and I might be able to give you another hint.

Comment: $4132, 4213$, and $3421$.

Comment: OK, one way to reason about why this set works is as follows: 1 has been blocked from the last 3 positions.  2 has also been blocked from the last 3 positions.  Therefore, for $\pi$ to not intersect any of these, 1 must be in the first position, but so must 2, which is impossible.  Now to the 2010 case.  With 1006 $\sigma$'s, 1 can be blocked from the last 1006 positions.  So $\pi$ must have 1 at one of the first 1004 positions.  How many values can you block from the last 1006 positions and therefore force into the first 1004 positions?

Comment: Is that 1005, but since there are only 1004 positions in front, so we have a contradiction?

Comment: Actually you can block 1006 numbers from the last 1006 positions, but blocking 1005 would also do the job, since there are only 1004 in front.  (E.g. in the small example, you could have chosen 4123, 4231, 4312 s.t. 3 numbers are blocked from the last 3 positions.)

Comment: Yes, indeed...now I get it already :)